# Skellige's quests level requirement

Tags: the-witcher-3

I was wondering what is the best level should I be on before moving to Skellige. I am currently pursuing the Dandelion quest, have finished all side-quests that I came across (Secondary and Witcher contracts), excluding those that require an extremely high level.

I am at Level 14 and if my calculations are correct I should be somewhere in level 15 before I finish the main quest in Novigrad. Maybe even 16 if I'm lucky.

I am asking because it seems every secondary quest that I came across recently require a level 20++ character and I am not sure whether Skellige will have secondary quests below that for me to grind.

EDIT:

it seems I've spoken early. I'm still in Novigrad and now I'm lvl 19 and moving close to reaching 20. Yeah the Dandelion quest was long and I tried doing some other quests that were not recommended because of my level and I was able to complete them, yes they were tough but not impossible.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question a bit. If you ask me the question is opinion based for now, the one will say "oh level 16 is perfect" others could say that they could manage it level 10. Maybe you should ask which level the quests in skellige have so the question can't be answered opinion based.

Comment: @Nitro.de nice observation. Title changed :)

Comment: There we go, first opinion based answer :P. However the Storyquest where you've to go to Skellige is for lvl 16. I could find out that a lot of monsters are way above lvl 16 maybe that helps for now.

Comment: @Nitro.de thats the thing it says 16 but I am running out of side quests that I can complete at my current level. I am not a big fan of Gwent but I guess its my only hope.

Comment: Hm just go with your current level. I'm playing on max difficulty and still can make quest 4-5 level above me.

Comment: @Nitro.de I am fine with 4 or 5 levels. I just don't wanna go there and have all the quests requiring level 30+

Comment: The Dandelion main quest and the following side quest is really long, so depending on where you are exactly with it there still might be many hours of content ahead of you in that one alone.

Comment: @MadScientist yeah, I played through most of it yesterday and now I'm on lvl 16 and still have much more to do. I guess I asked this question too soon :)

Answer (score 1):

The main story quest on Skellige is marked as level 16, and it is not particularly difficult combat-wise. You should have no issue doing it, and it'll give you a nice bunch of XP.

There are some other quests on Skellige around level 16-20, so there should be enough to do there. You are more likely to accidentally run into enemies that far outlevel you on Skellige, so you have to be a bit more careful.

Equipment can matter a lot, so if you're having a hard time make sure you have the appropriate witcher set items for your level, or other good gear.

I did switch around Skellige and Velen/Novigrad between levels 15 and 19, there is content on both maps for these levels. I'd recommend to just try out the main quest on Skellige, it should help you level up and you'll find a few more quests for your level on the way. The main quests grant a lot of experience, more than anything else you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding most of the main story quests okay at level 16 but I have to say that some of the monsters you encounter, especially around some of the unknown markers, and many Witcher contracts involving monsters often seem to be too difficult. Many are at level 26 and higher. One Relict I encountered (I'll not name it to avoid spoiler) was particularly nasty, easily killing me in 2 or three swipes or killed outright with one good charge, despite my Enhanced Griffin armor, correct bombs used and appropriate oil applied. I might try my luck again if I get find a suitable decoction recipe though I later discovered it was a level 29 contract.

Comment: Well I'm on level 18 and counting. Will try and push to lvl 20 before moving on

Answer (score 0):

I went in at level 19,tons of stuff to do in novigrad,playing blood and broken bones 
Be patient and get to a high level,enemies though tough will feel lyk a breeze

Answer (score -1):

I went at level 17. If you do some secondary missions then you'll get to level 17 in no time. You could go now if you wish to do so, however you may find it a bit more challenging.